# Triple integral with exponential probability density functions

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

I am trying to calculate the closed expression for the following integral:

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{-2\sqrt{xz}}^{+2\sqrt{xz}}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^\frac{3}{2}}\exp{\left(-\frac{(x - \mu)^2 + (y - \mu)^2 + (z - \mu)^2}{2}\right)}dy\ dx\ dz
$$

Here $\mu$ can be any real number.

**Context:** The integrand is the product of the probability distribution functions of $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ which are i.i.d. $\text{Normal}(\mu, 1)$ variates. The region of integration is the positive branch of the infinite elliptic cone $y^2\leq4xz$. I need to calculate it for the other branch as well, but if I can understand the technique for one branch, I can do it for the other one.

**Progress**: I know that when $\mu=0$, the value is around $0.176$. Courtesy of [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=triple+integral&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22TripleIntegral%22%2C+%22rangeend2m%22%7D+-%3E%22infinity%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22TripleIntegral%22%2C+%22rangeend1i%22%7D+-%3E%22%2B2*sqrt%28xz%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22TripleIntegral%22%2C+%22intvariable1i%22%7D+-%3E%22y%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22TripleIntegral%22%2C+%22rangestart3%22%7D+-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22TripleIntegral%22%2C+%22rangestart2m%22%7D+-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22triple+integral%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22TripleIntegral%22%2C+%22integrand%22%7D+-%3E%22exp%28-%28x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+%2B+z%5E2%29%2F2%29%2F%28%282*pi%29%5E%283%2F2%29%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22TripleIntegral%22%2C+%22rangestart1i%22%7D+-%3E%22-2*sqrt%28xz%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22TripleIntegral%22%2C+%22intvariable2m%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22TripleIntegral%22%2C+%22intvariable3%22%7D+-%3E%22z%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22TripleIntegral%22%2C+%22rangeend3%22%7D+-%3E%22infinity%22).

My intention is to evaluate the integral for several values of $\mu$ using a closed expression (free from integrals) involving $\mu$, assuming that it is possible. If such a form does not exist, I can make do with an efficient way of evaluating the integral numerically.

How should I proceed here? Will a transformation of variables be useful? Is solving it numerically the recommended way to do it?

Also, has it been done before? (It probably has been but I couldn't find it.)